# How do I handle an array of checkboxes in ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, checkbox, ejs

I'm using ejs for my webpages and have one page where I have an array of objects. I don't know how many objects I have when the page loads. It's a page where I can edit a set of announcements. I'd like to use a checkbox to enable or disable each announcement, but need to set them initially from the incoming values. The page looks like this:
[image]
I'm using a foreach in the code for the page:

```
<% var i=0; %>
<% announcements.forEach(function(announcement) { %>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="enabled<%= i %>" name="enabled[<%= i %>]"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"><%= announcement.text %></td>
    <td><%= type %></td>
    <td>
        <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
        <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<%      i++; %>
<% }) %>
```

How do I set the initial values of the checkboxes for each row? I have used the variable i to uniquely identify the checkboxes, but I don't know how to find the number of rows in the script portion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the initial values on the input element itself.

For this example, I'll assume you have a value coming in to indicate whether an announcement is "enabled" or not:

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" id="enabled<%= i %>" name="enabled[<%= i %>]" <%= announcement.enabled ? "checked" : null %> >
</td>
```

That's a little terse - here's an alternative example that does the same thing:

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" id="enabled<%= i %>" name="enabled[<%= i %>]" <% if (announcement.enabled) { %> "checked" <% } %> >
</td>
```

Comment: Yep! I see what you did and I think that will work. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note to confirm, that this did indeed work. I should have seen that myself! (Isn't that always the case. :-) )

Comment: Woot! I'm glad it helped. :)